# How to get rid of a class within <a> tag when other <a> tag is being hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css

### Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<style>

.topnav {
background-color: white;
}

.topnav a {
color: black;
padding: 14px 16px;
font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
background-color: blue;
color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
background-color: blue;
color: white;
}

<body>
<div id = 'menu' class = 'topnav'>
<a id = 'inactivate' class = 'active' href = 'first'>First</a>
<a href = 'second'>Second</a>
<a href = 'third'>Third</a>
<a href = 'fourth'>Fourth</a>
</div>
</body>
</style>
</html>
```

### What it does:

It creates a navegation bar, `topnav`, which consists of three hyperlinks: `first`, `second`, `third` and `fourth`. By default, each hyperlink has a black font and has a white background, except for `first`, who has a white font and a blue background.

### Goal

When the user hovers over a hyperlink which is not `first`, it makes the hovered hyperlink have a white font and a blue background, then it sets `first` to a black font and white background.

### What I've tried: I coded a script using JavaScript

```
<script>
var element = document.getElementById('inactivate');
element.classList.remove('active');
</script>
```

I placed the script in

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<style>

.topnav a:hover {
---
script
---
}

</style>
</html>
```

However, it didn't work. The script works, though. I just don't know **how to make the script run when a hyperlink is hovered**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following adds an event listener to the `#menu` `div` and uses *event bubbling* to capture mouseover events. Then, it only logs "do thing" when the target's `tagName` is `A` (i.e., it's a link) and the target's `id` isn't `"inactivate"` since you don't want the hover effect on the first link.

In the following code, you can swap out what you actually want to execute where I have the `console.log`.

```js
const menu = document.querySelector("#menu");

menu.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName === "A" && e.target.id !== "inactivate") {
    console.log("do thing");
  }
})
```

```html
<div id = 'menu' class = 'topnav'>
  <a id = 'inactivate' class = 'active' href = 'first'>First</a>
  <a href='second'>Second</a>
  <a href='third'>Third</a>
  <a href='fourth'>Fourth</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> When the user hovers over a hyperlink which is not first, it makes the
> hovered hyperlink have a white font and a blue background, then it
> sets first to a black font and white background.

Can be achieved without javascript, with `.topnav:hover a.active:not(:hover),`

```css
.topnav:hover a.active:not(:hover),
.topnav a {
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: white;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#">First</a>
  <a href="#">Second</a>
  <a href="#">Third</a>
  <a href="#">Fourth</a>
</div>
```

Comment: TBH I feel like this one should be accepted

Answer (score 0):

Not that hard, use JQuery!
Here, I made a simple example here

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("nav a").hover(function() {
        $("nav a").removeClass("active");
        
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
    
    $("nav a").mouseout(function() {
        $("nav a").removeClass("active");
        $(".first").addClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
a {
    color: #000;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    transition-duration: 300ms;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

a.active {
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
    <a href="#" class="first active">First</a>
    <a href="#">Second</a>
    <a href="#">Third</a>
    <a href="#">Fourth</a>
</nav>
```